# Representation of spin-$1/2$ operators in terms of Majorana fermions

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-spin, majorana-fermions

I am reading *Quantum Field Theory in Condensed Matter Physics* by A.M. Tsvelik. In Chapter 20, it is claimed that introducing three Majorana fermions 
$\gamma^\mu_i$ on each site $i$ of the lattice (such that
$\{\gamma^\mu_i,\gamma^\nu_j\}=\delta^{\mu,\nu}\delta_{i,j}$),
spin-$1/2$ operators can be expressed as
   $$S_i^\lambda=-{i\over 2}\epsilon_{\lambda\mu\nu}
   \gamma_i^\mu\gamma_i^\nu$$
I am trying to show the commutations relations
   $$[S_i^\lambda,S_j^\rho]=i\epsilon_{\lambda\rho\sigma}S^\sigma_i
    \delta_{i,j}$$
Unfortunately, my calculation is wrong (by a factor 2). I would be very grateful if somebody could find the mistake.

I start with
   $$[S_i^\lambda,S_j^\rho]
    =-{1\over 4}\epsilon_{\lambda\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\rho\zeta\xi}
   \big(\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_i^\nu\gamma_j^\zeta\gamma_j^\xi
   -\gamma_j^\zeta\gamma_j^\xi\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_i^\nu\big)$$
Using the anti-commutation relations between Majorana, I get
  $$\eqalign{
  \gamma_j^\zeta\gamma_j^\xi\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_i^\nu
  &=\gamma_j^\zeta\big(\delta^{\xi,\mu}\delta_{i,j}
  -\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_j^\xi\big)\gamma_i^\nu             \cr
  &=\delta^{\xi,\mu}\delta_{i,j}\gamma_j^\zeta\gamma_i^\nu
  -\big(\delta^{\mu,\zeta}\delta_{i,j}-\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_j^\zeta\big)
  \big(\delta^{\nu,\xi}\delta_{i,j}-\gamma_i^\nu\gamma_j^\xi\big)\cr
  &=\delta^{\xi,\mu}\delta_{i,j}\gamma_j^\zeta\gamma_i^\nu
  +\delta^{\mu,\zeta}\delta_{i,j}\gamma_i^\nu\gamma_j^\xi
  +\delta^{\nu,\xi}\delta_{i,j}\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_j^\zeta
  -\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_j^\zeta\gamma_i^\nu\gamma_j^\xi
  -\delta^{\mu,\zeta}\delta^{\nu,\xi}\delta_{i,j}                \cr
  &=\big(\delta^{\xi,\mu}\gamma_j^\zeta\gamma_i^\nu
  \!+\!\delta^{\mu,\zeta}\gamma_i^\nu\gamma_j^\xi
  \!+\!\delta^{\nu,\xi}\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_j^\zeta\big)\delta_{i,j}
  -\gamma_i^\mu\big(\delta^{\nu,\zeta}\delta_{i,j}
  -\gamma_i^\nu\gamma_j^\zeta\big)\gamma_j^\xi
  -\delta^{\mu,\zeta}\delta^{\nu,\xi}\delta_{i,j}                \cr
  &=\big(\delta^{\xi,\mu}\gamma_j^\zeta\gamma_i^\nu
  +\delta^{\mu,\zeta}\gamma_i^\nu\gamma_j^\xi
  +\delta^{\nu,\xi}\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_j^\zeta
  -\delta^{\nu,\zeta}\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_j^\xi\big)
  +\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_i^\nu\gamma_j^\zeta\gamma_j^\xi
  -\delta^{\mu,\zeta}\delta^{\nu,\xi}\delta_{i,j}                \cr
  }$$
so that the commutator reads
  $$[\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_i^\nu,\gamma_j^\zeta\gamma_j^\xi]
  =-\big(\delta^{\xi,\mu}\gamma_j^\zeta\gamma_i^\nu
  +\delta^{\mu,\zeta}\gamma_i^\nu\gamma_j^\xi
  +\delta^{\nu,\xi}\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_j^\zeta
  -\delta^{\nu,\zeta}\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_j^\xi\big)
  +\delta^{\mu,\zeta}\delta^{\nu,\xi}\delta_{i,j}$$
Since $(\gamma_i^\mu)^2=1/2$ for Majorana fermions, 
  $$\eqalign{
  \epsilon_{\lambda\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\rho\zeta\xi}
  \delta^{\xi,\mu}\gamma_i^\zeta\gamma_i^\nu
  &=-\epsilon_{\lambda\nu\mu}\epsilon_{\rho\zeta\mu}\gamma_i^\zeta\gamma_i^\nu\cr
  &=-\big(\delta^{\lambda,\rho}\delta^{\nu,\zeta}
  -\delta^{\lambda,\zeta}\delta^{\nu,\rho}\big)\gamma_i^\zeta\gamma_i^\nu\cr
  &=-\delta^{\lambda,\rho}\big(\gamma_i^\zeta\big)^2
  +\gamma_i^\lambda\gamma_i^\rho                \cr
  &=-{3\over 2}\delta^{\lambda,\rho}+\gamma_i^\lambda\gamma_i^\rho         \cr
  }$$
because of the implicit sum over $\zeta$ in the first term. Similarly,
  $$\eqalign{
  &\epsilon_{\lambda\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\rho\zeta\xi}
  \delta^{\mu,\zeta}\gamma_i^\nu\gamma_j^\xi
  ={3\over 2}\delta^{\lambda,\rho}-\gamma_i^\rho\gamma_i^\lambda\cr
  &\epsilon_{\lambda\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\rho\zeta\xi}
  \delta^{\nu,\xi}\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_j^\zeta
  ={3\over 2}\delta^{\lambda,\rho}-\gamma_i^\rho\gamma_i^\lambda\cr
  &\epsilon_{\lambda\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\rho\zeta\xi}
  \delta^{\nu,\zeta}\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_j^\xi
  =-{3\over 2}\delta^{\lambda,\rho}+\gamma_i^\rho\gamma_i^\lambda\cr
  }$$
so that
  $$\eqalign{
  \delta^{\xi,\mu}\gamma_j^\zeta\gamma_i^\nu
  +\delta^{\mu,\zeta}\gamma_i^\nu\gamma_j^\xi
  +\delta^{\nu,\xi}\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_j^\zeta
  -\delta^{\nu,\zeta}\gamma_i^\mu\gamma_j^\xi
  &=3\delta^{\lambda,\rho}+\gamma_i^\lambda\gamma_i^\rho
  -3\gamma_i^\rho\gamma_i^\lambda\cr
  &=3\delta^{\lambda,\rho}+\gamma_i^\lambda\gamma_i^\rho
  -3\big(\delta^{\lambda,\rho}-\gamma_i^\lambda\gamma_i^\rho\big)\cr
  &=4\gamma_i^\lambda\gamma_i^\rho\cr
  }$$
The last term of the commutator is
  $$\epsilon_{\lambda\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\rho\zeta\xi}
  \delta^{\mu,\zeta}\delta^{\nu,\xi}
  =\epsilon_{\lambda\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\rho\mu\nu}
  =\delta^{\lambda,\rho}$$
so
  $$\eqalign{
  [S_i^\lambda,S_j^\rho]
  &={1\over 4}\big(4\gamma_i^\lambda\gamma_i^\rho
  -\delta^{\lambda,\rho}\big)\delta_{i,j}      \cr
  }$$
This result is unfortunately **wrong**! I expect instead
  $$\eqalign{
  i\epsilon_{\lambda\rho\sigma}S_i^\sigma
  &={1\over 2}\epsilon_{\lambda\rho\sigma} \epsilon_{\sigma\zeta\xi}
  \gamma_i^\zeta\gamma_i^\xi\cr
  &={1\over 2}\epsilon_{\lambda\rho\sigma} \epsilon_{\zeta\xi\sigma}
  \gamma_i^\zeta\gamma_i^\xi\cr
  &={1\over 2}\big(\gamma_i^\lambda\gamma_i^\rho
  -\gamma_i^\rho\gamma_i^\lambda\big)           \cr
  &={1\over 2}\big(2\gamma_i^\lambda\gamma_i^\rho-\delta^{\lambda,\rho}\big)
  }$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you dealt with the last term, product of deltas, you missed a factor of two:
\begin{equation}
\epsilon_{\lambda\mu\nu} \epsilon_{\rho\mu\nu} = {\color{red}2}\delta^{\lambda,\rho}
\end{equation}